# SwiftUI is missing UITouch properties

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture, uitouch

When using `UIKit` for touch events, you will get the `UITouch` which has the `UITouch.force`, `UITouch.majorRadius`

but When using `SwiftUI`, the `dragGesture`, or any Gesture, you won't get the `UITouch`,
instead, you will get a value that has only touch coordinates `x,y`, but no `force` and `majorRadius`

how can get the `force` and the `majorRadius` in pure `SwiftUI` without using `UIKit`?

SwiftUI
[image]

UIKit
[image: UIKit]

Comment: Gesture is gesture, touch is touch... they are different things.

Comment: So how can I get the touch.force and touch.majorRadius in SwiftUI without UIkit?

Comment: Not today, there is no native API for that, so either defer transition to SwiftUI or try to use UIViewRepresentable as a bridge.

Comment: UIViewRepresentable that's nice but I don't want UIkit in my app. My app is pure swiftui only

Comment: In which case you don't get those properties as they aren't available in SwiftUI (yet?). Can't have it both ways.

Comment: It is the same as cut left hand only because one is right-handed... but... it is your app ‍♂️. @ZivAdler... and by the way, you will not be able to get what you wanted because half of SwiftUI backend is still on UIKit engines.

Comment: Is there something similar to force and majorRadius in pure SwiftUI?

Comment: As Asperi said, there is no SwiftUI API that registers force.

Comment: @Asperi SwiftUI using UIKit on backend is encouraging. However, with UIViewRepresentable, a SwiftUI Drag gesture will block UITouch(s). Oddly, UITouch doesn't block a SwiftUI Drag. Weird.